# Find carret position x y inside textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, position, prediction

What Im trying to do is - i dont know the name maybe - a Prediction Help Inputter inside a textarea. It uses jquery autocomplete. When the user types '[[g ' inside textarea (id=test), a input with autocomplete is opened (id=example), so it search in 'data'. When the user find the desired data, he must press Shif+Enter to insert the data into the textarea, closing with ']]'.

**How could I find the position of the carret to make the input appears near there?**

I dont want to find the index of the carret, but something like the x y absolute position.

What do you suggest me?

Code above:

```
<textarea onkeydown="predicao(this);" cols="40" rows="10" id="test" onfocus="this.focus()"></textarea>
<input id="example" style="display: none;" onkeyup="insert(this, event);"/>

<script language="Javascript">
<!--

function predicao(objeto){
    comprimento = objeto.value.length;
    var antipenultimo = comprimento - 4;
    var input = objeto.value.substring(antipenultimo,comprimento);
    var output = "";
    for(i=0; i<input.length; ++i){
        if(output != "") output += ", ";
        output += input.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    if (output == "91, 91, 103, 32"){

        var preditor = document.getElementById('example');
        preditor.value = '';
        preditor.style.display = 'block';
        preditor.focus();
        preditor.select();
    }  
}
function insert(objeto, evt){
    var e = evt || event;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(e.shiftKey && code == '13') {
        var texto = document.getElementById('test').value;
        texto += objeto.value+']]';
        document.getElementById('test').focus();
        document.getElementById('test').value = texto;
        objeto.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = "Afrikaans Català Deutsch English Esperanto Suomi Français Galego Hrvatski Magyar Bahasa Indonesia Italiano Basa Jawa".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var pos = $('textarea').caret(); // using caret plugin...
var lines = $('textarea').val().slice(0, pos).replace(/\t/g, '    ').split('\n');
var y = lines.length;
var x = lines[y-1].length;
```

Should work reasonably well for fix-width fonts.

Comment: I downloaded all vesions of caret plugin here http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret this plugins is not working. It returns something like Unexpected token Illegal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do it via JS only:

```
function doGetCaretPosition (ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;   // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
    ctrl.focus ();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();
        Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    return (CaretPos);
}
```

Courtesy: http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/
Demo: http://demo.vishalon.net/getset.htm

Comment: I found this blog on google, but i did not understand how I could use this. My idea is found some x y position to give a top, left position em px to a div container with the input box.